# How do I use other fonts than HERSHEY with the OpenCV & Python cvPutText()?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I am currently using cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX and I want to use a font like sfui-regular.ttf

Comment: I guess OpenCV provides support for some basic fonts only, However you may use some other library to Render the font as a png image and then over it on image using OpenCV

Comment: Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782756/a-better-way-to-add-text-to-ca-cvmat-than-cvputtext/30783400#30783400